# Set var in javascript to values in tags

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set a var in javascript to a value inside a tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to return the value of its value attribute.</p>

<button id="myButton" value="value1" onclick="myFunction()">1</button>
<button id="myButton" value="value2" onclick="myFunction()">2</button>

<p id="output"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myButton").value;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The above code obviously doesn't work since id is unique so doesn't matter which button I click it will show "value1" regardless.

Is there a way to make it so that clicking the "1" button will show "value1" and the "2" button will show "value2"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<button value="value1" onclick="myFunction(this)">1</button>
<button value="value2" onclick="myFunction(this)">2</button>

<script>
function myFunction(button) {
    var x = button.value;
    button.innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```

Comment: @Andrew L. Actually, you can have an infinite amount of elements with the same 'id'. It is valid HTML. Nothing will stop you from doing so. It is just not handy for CSS and Javascript selecting ;)... I just copy/pasted the code from OP, that's why it was like that :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `this` inside function so it refers to element that is clicked

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = e.value;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to return the value of its value attribute.</p>
<button value="value1" onclick="myFunction(this)">1</button>
<button value="value2" onclick="myFunction(this)">2</button>

<p id="output"></p>
```